# GitHub to Heroku Commit Error

Tags: git, heroku

Am using Aptana Studio 3 and Heroku for a RoR website project. When I push my site to Heroku after a 'commit' via GitHub I keep getting this error. Have searched everywhere but can't find a simple solution that I can follow. Any advice what has happened and how to reslove? Thx.

```
User$ git push heroku master
To git@heroku.com:xxxxxx.git
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:xxxxxx.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected.
Merge the remote changes before pushing again.
See 'non-fast forward' section of 'git push --help' for details.
User$
```

I tried this suggestion as per below from @SkillDrick and got this plus the error at the end:

```
User$ git merge heroku/master master
usage: git merge [options] <remote>...
or: git merge [options] <msg> HEAD <remote>

-n                    do not show a diffstat at the end of the merge
--stat                show a diffstat at the end of the merge
--summary             (synonym to --stat)
--log                 add list of one-line log to merge commit message
--squash              create a single commit instead of doing a merge
--commit              perform a commit if the merge succeeds (default)
--ff                  allow fast forward (default)
-s, --strategy <strategy>
                      merge strategy to use
-m, --message <message>
                      message to be used for the merge commit (if any)
-v, --verbose         be more verbose
-q, --quiet           be more quiet



user$ git push heroku master
To git@heroku.com:worrybin.git
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:worrybin.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected.
Merge the remote changes before pushing again.
See 'non-fast forward' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: When you did `git merge heroku/master master` (my mistake) and it said `usage` etc, that was telling you that the command was incorrect, so it didn't actually merge.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. A very simple solution would be to force the push anyways:

git push heroku master -f

Since heroku is just being used to deploy your App(and not for source control like origin/master) this should be fine.

Answer (score 5):

For some reason your Heroku repo has diverged. You could do:

```
git fetch heroku
git merge heroku/master
git push heroku master
```

which will "Merge the remote changes before pushing again." Before you merge, maybe do `git diff heroku/master` to find out what's *actually* different.

Comment: thanks for suggestion. Tried it and got the same error again - have posted details above.

Comment: @ubique sorry, I wrote it wrong. The second command should just be `git merge heroku/master`.

Comment: getting this message now... any ideas? **user$ git merge heroku/master** 
error: Untracked working tree file '._.DS_Store' would be overwritten by merge.
fatal: merging of trees 5a008289e74cc3eb95880b1cf51b532c6aed66b2 and 6073db0f540dc1960070d996fd93484aab73439b failed

Answer (score 0):

Do a `git pull` and then do the `git push`

Comment: **git pull** returns 'already up to date' and **git push** returns 'everything up to date'. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Like manojlds said, do a git pull first.

Actually before doing anything check your local repo if you have any changes.

```
git status
```

if there are none, do a `git pull heroku master`. If there are changes, either commit or stash them.(I'd say just stash them for now)

After you have pulled(hopefully without any conflicts), do a git push heroku master and you should be all set. If you have conflicts, resolve them first, commit, then push.

What basically happened is that your heroku repo has diverged from your current one. This happens mostly in the following scenario:

1. UserA makes changes, pushes to heroku and your github repo.
2. UserB pulls, makes changes, pushes to the heroku repo and forgets to push to github.
3. UserA pulls from github and tries to push to heroku.

In that case, you are userA and that means you pulled something that wasn't in heroku.